# how to set an option for form->input( 'multiple'=>'checkbox')

Tags: php, cakephp

i plan to set a checkbox with selected option in my form.
but i am unable to show my checkbox content in the form, i cant see any value instead of just a box for me to select.

how to show value while i using checkbox? i able to show my value while i using select.
this is in a HABTM model. any hints?

here is my selection code.

> input('User',array('label'
>   => 'Select Related Potential',
>   'multiple'=>'checkbox',             
>                      //'options' => $users,                                  
>   'legend'=>$users,                                  
>   //'value'=>$users,                                     
>   //'id'=>$ownUserId,                                   
>   'default'=>$ownUserId,
>         'style'=>'width:200px;height:100px',
>         'selected' => $ownUserId,   )); ?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://book.cakephp.org/view/755/options-default) may be relevant:

> You cannot use `default` to check a checkbox - instead you might set the value in `$this->data` in your controller, `$form->data` in your view, or set the input option `checked` to `true`.

---

For example:

```
// in Controller
$this->data['Model']['field'] = true;
```

Causes the field to have the value `true`, which will result in a checked checkbox for this field.

Or:

```
$form->input('Model.field', array('checked' => true));
```

Always checks the checkbox.

Or:

```
$form->input('Model.field', array(
    'checked' => ($this->data['Model']['field'] == 'xxx')
));
```

Dynamically sets the checkbox based on whether `$this->data['Model']['field']` is 'xxx' or not.

---

Sorry, completely misunderstood the question.

Did you [find your users via `list`](http://book.cakephp.org/view/810/find-list)? The options array needs to be in a particular format, a normal `find()` won't do that.

Comment: not really understand how to perform that. what should i write for checked to true?? and i wanted to show all my compact data on checkbox. thanks for information, i need know more.. =)

Comment: See updated answer. What do you mean by "show all compact data on checkbox"?

Comment: i mean, when my 'options' => $users, but the select checkbox din't show my $users information which i had $this->set(compact('user')); in my controller. 

the select list just show out few checkbox, but doesn't show any of the words, how can i show some value beside the checkbox, at least other know what is the checkbox for. thanks for ur update. i understand it much better. =)